# R: Counting consecutive letters in a string

Tags: r, string, dataframe, count

I currently have a string in R that looks like this:

```
df <- c ("BMMBMMBMMMMMBMMBM")
```

I need to determine how many times  MM's appear in this string (in this example it's 4).

I've been using `str_count(df, "MM")` but this only counts how many times two M's are next to each other in the string (which returns 5).

Any help would be great...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is:

```
stringr::str_count(df, "MM+")
#output
[1] 4
```

`+` means one or more

in base R:

```
lengths(gregexpr("MM+", df))
```

`gregexpr` returns a list, each element corresponds to one element of `df`.
`lengths` returns the length of each list element.

EDIT: as per the comment by @docendo discimus the second option is a little dangerous since it will return `1` if the string was not found.

```
lengths(gregexpr("xyz+", df))
#output
1
```

A safer option is:

```
lapply(gregexpr("MM+", df), function(x) length(x[x > 0]))
#output
[[1]]
[1] 4

lapply(gregexpr("xyz+", df), function(x) length(x[x > 0]))
#output
[[1]]
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R approach without regular expressions:

```
with(rle(unlist(strsplit(x, ""))), sum(values == "M" & lengths >= 2))
# [1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Base solution:

```
s <- "BMMBMMBMMMMMBMMBM"
lengths(gregexpr("MM+", s))
## [1] 4
```

Note that the input called `df` in the question is a character string, not a data frame, and `c("X")` is identical to `"X"` so the `c` and the parentheses are not needed.

Comment: Without further checks, this can cause trouble if the string is not found at all.

Comment: If that is a possibility try `lengths(gregexpr("MM+", paste("MM", s)))-1` .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

```
str_count(df,"(M)\\1+")
```

This will count two or more M as one case.
Or

```
str_count(df,"M{2,}")
```